# Event lisener works only one time

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, dom

I have a code for changing CSS when scroll value >= 500:

```
 var appearScroll = function(){
            let fline = document.getElementById("skills__listone");
            var skills = document.getElementById("skills");
            var baselocation = 0;
            fline.style.opacity = 0;
            var distance = window.pageYOffset;
            window.addEventListener("click", function(){
                if ( distance >= 600 ){
                    fline.style.opacity = 1;
                }
            })
            
            
    
        };
        appearScroll();
```

This works only one time for example when scroll value is 200 and I click the mouse, there are nothing happens(It is ok, because distance >= 600), but when scroll value, for example 700, there are nothing happens, because click function already was running. the function have to observe for the distance value and depend on IT make a result

Comment: A line like `var distance = window.pageYOffset;` will not extend into the future, however you can simply use `if (window.pageYOffset > 600)` in your listener function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var distance = window.pageYOffset;` this line should be inside the click event function to get the current `window.pageYOffset` value on every click.

**like this:**

```
window.addEventListener("click", function(){
   var distance = window.pageYOffset; // <-- here
   if ( distance >= 600 ){
       fline.style.opacity = 1;
   }
})
```

Comment: May you also add why this should be the case?